# Typescript extends keyword not working

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I'm developing my first game using Visual Studio, Phaser and Typescript.

I can't get my classes to work when I use the extends key word

This works:

```
class Game  {

game: Phaser.Game;

constructor() {
    // init game
    this.game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio - 20, window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio - 20, Phaser.CANVAS, 'content', State);
}
}
```

This does not:

```
class Game extends Phaser.Game{

constructor() {
    // init game

    super(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio - 20, window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio - 20, Phaser.CANVAS, 'content', State);
}
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out all day without success, can anybody shed some light on it?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What error are you getting?

Comment: When I run the game using the extends keyword I get a blank screen, the error thrown is: Uncaught ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script tag for phaser.js needs to be above the script tag for your script.

Each script runs in order and your second example has an immediate dependency on the `Phaser` object already being created as soon as it runs.

Comment: Thank you so much, how did you know this was my problem? I'm very grateful, That was a silly mistake on my part.